# Action Sheet on Iphone and Ipad errors Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift, uiactionsheet

I'm new to Swift and trying to figure out how it works. I'm having a problem with the Alert Sheet. On iPhone 5S is working fine (it opens the Sheet and then the Facebook and Twitter alert) but I'm getting the error: "LaunchServices: invalidationHandler called".
On an iPad Air 2, with the code I have, the alert opens but its position (and the arrow) is not next to the shareACtion button, but actually on the opposite side of the screen. Besides, it's not doing any action.
I've imported the Social framework and the UIActionSheetDelegate.
Thanx

```
@IBAction func shareAction(sender: AnyObject) {
   let  actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: nil, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK", destructiveButtonTitle: nil,otherButtonTitles: "Twitter", "Facebook")
        actionSheet.showInView(self.view)
}
    func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int)
    {
        switch buttonIndex{
        //Twitter
        case 1:
            SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter)
            var tweetSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
            tweetSheet.setInitialText("I'm using the app Test")
            tweetSheet.addImage(UIImage(named: "picture1.png"))
            self.presentViewController(tweetSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
            break;
        //Facebook
        case 2:
            SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook)
            var FBSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
            FBSheet.setInitialText("I'm using the app Test")
            FBSheet.addImage(UIImage(named: "picture1.png"))
            self.presentViewController(FBSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

}

Comment: Not sure about your problem but the UIActionSheet (and also its delegate) has been deprecated in iOS8. Instead it is recommended that you use UIAlertController.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for `UIActionSheet.showInView(_:)`

> On iPad, this method centers the action sheet in the middle of the
>   screen. Generally, if you want to present an action sheet in an iPad
>   application, you should use the showFromRect:inView:animated: method
>   to display the action sheet instead.

From the documentation for `UIActionSheet.showFromRect(_, inView:, animated:)`

> On iPad, this method displays the action sheet in a popover whose
>   arrow points to the specified rectangle of the view. The popover does
>   not overlap the specified rectangle.

In your code you are passing a rectangle with a 0, 0 origin and 0, 0 size. I bet your action sheet is showing up in the upper left corner. Instead, pass in the frame of the view you want the sheet to point to (assuming that view is attached to the main view.) If you view is attached to some sub-view, then you also have to change which view you are passing.

The documentation is your friend.

Comment: I've tried shwFromRect @Daniel and that's when the alert is showing in the wrong position: not next to the button but on the opposite side of the screen. Besides, it's not working: cannot post on Facebook nor on Twitter.

Comment: Show us the code that uses showFromRect:inView:animated: and I will tell you why it shows on the opposite side of the screen. Likely, you are passing in the wrong view. As for why you cannot post to Facebook or Twitter, one problem at a time.

Comment: @IBAction func shareAction(sender: AnyObject) {
       let  actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: nil, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK", destructiveButtonTitle: nil,otherButtonTitles: "Twitter", "Facebook")
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
            actionSheet.showFromRect(CGRect(), inView: self.view, animated: true)
        }else{
            actionSheet.showInView(self.view)}
    }

Comment: The rest is the same as the code above. Thanx @Daniel

Comment: I added to my answer.

Comment: I've followed @Magnas suggestion and I've used UIAlertController. Problem solved. All working fine now. Thanx for your time Daniel